# Equality of extensions of Jordan measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I find the following theorem in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis* (p. 280 of [this Russian ed.](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf), p. 26 of 1963 Graylock English ed.):

> In order that two extensions $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ of measures $m_1$ defined on rings $\mathfrak{R}_1$ and $\mathfrak{R}_2$ coincide, it is necessary and sufficient that$$\mathfrak{R}_1\subseteq S_{\mu_2},\quad m_1(A)=\mu_2(A)\text{ on }\mathfrak{R}_1,$$$$\mathfrak{R}_2\subseteq S_{\mu_1},\quad m_2(A)=\mu_1(A)\text{ on }\mathfrak{R}_2.$$

where $S_{\mu_k}$ is the sistem of measurable sets with respect to Jordan measure $\mu_k$. I would say that it is implicitly assumed that $\forall A\in S_{\mu_1}\quad\exists B\in\mathfrak{R}_2: A\subseteq B$ and that $\forall A\in S_{\mu_2}\quad\exists B\in\mathfrak{R}_1: A\subseteq B$: am I right? In absence of such a hypothesis I do not see how it would be even posssible to define the Jordan outer measure $\bar{\mu}_k(A)=\inf_{B\in\mathfrak{R}_k,A\subseteq B}m_k(B)$...

Thank you very much for any answer!!!

Comment: Read carefully the two preceding problems. Then, if $\mathscr R_1 \subseteq \mathscr S_{\mu_2}\,$, then $\mathscr R_1 \subseteq \mathscr A_2$. So the assumption is present. The same for $\mathscr R_2$ of course.

Comment: I suspected that, otherwise I would not have found much sense in the Jordan measure of $A$. I heartily thank you!